# Wondering if mySQL tables can be named using date functions and mySQL #1064 error

Tags: mysql

```
Noob Alert.
```

Hi. I'm trying to input this event in mySQL through phpMyAdmin. I'm not sure if the table can be named using YEAR() and MONTHNAME() functions. Even before i could tackle that, this #1064 error has sprouted:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'END' at line 14
```

Could someone please point out what i'm doing wrong? 
Also is it possible to name tables the way I'm trying to?

```
CREATE EVENT newmonthlytable
ON SCHEDULE EVERY '1' MONTH
STARTS '2012-09-01 00:00:00'
DO
BEGIN
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `YEAR()-MONTHNAME()-0-msgs` 
(`msgid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
`sender` int(11) NOT NULL, 
`reciever` int(11) NOT NULL, 
`sendername` varchar(64) NOT NULL, 
`msg` varchar(512) NOT NULL, 
`tstamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) 
ENGINE = MyISAM, CHARACTER SET = utf8, COLLATE = utf8_bin
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

There is syntax error, to fix it add ';' at the end of CREATE TABLE statement.

You can name tables as you want, but do you really need it? It is better to think about the db-design, and do not create tables from routines.

Comment: Its kind of a necessity to create tables automayically. these tables store messages shared between users of a social networking site (not actually, its just a project). assuming each of 10000 users sends 100 messages a month, a table is filled with 1 mil. records. Isn't it more logical to create a new table for next month? (I am a total noob, so I might be completely wrong.)